# Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.lang.Long]

Tags: scala, cassandra

I wrote this simple program in scala to query cassandra

```
val session = cass.session
lazy val stmt = cass.session.prepare(
   """
     |select token(id), id, date, rId, tt
     | from foo
     | where token(id) > ?
     | and token(id) <= ?;
   """.stripMargin
)

lazy val statement = stmt.bind().setLong(0, start).setLong(1, end)

def fromRow(row: Row): Foo = {
   val token = row.getLong(0)
   val id = row.getLong(1)
   val date = row.getLong(2)
   val rId = row.getLong(3)
   val tt = row.getInt(4)
   Foo(id, date, rId, tt)
}
```

However this code fails with error

```
[error] (run-main-4) com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.lang.Long]
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.lang.Long]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:679)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:526)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:506)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.access$200(CodecRegistry.java:140)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:211)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:208)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
```

Answer (score 11):

With driver v4.0, `timestamp` is mapped to `java.time.Instant`, so:
`stmt.bind(Instant.ofEpochSecond(start), Instant.ofEpochSecond(end))`

Comment: Yes I know, but in question there wasnt't information about version, and someone may come here now to find answer for his issue (like me this morning).

Comment: THANKS TO KUBA WENTA! Great thinking!

Answer (score 3):

According to link [here](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/java-driver-user/pAoLlEzmGWA/1mebnRHgIgAJ), bind var of type `Date` to your statement:

```
stmt.bind(new Date(start), new Date(end))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Table FOO , there is a **timestamp** Type Column  but you pass **Long** Value at your insertion query to that Column. May Be You Define **date** column type as **timestamp**.  Insert a **timestamp** type value '2012-12-07T10:00:00-0000' look like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> org.joda.time.DateTime]
```

I was getting above error, so i had to convert Date format instead of other formats. So you need to convert your value desired type

```
DateTime.now().toDate
```